# Simplicity decider

Tags: ruby, file

I was interested in the Code Golf challange about simple text. The spec is:

> Write a function that from a text returns the non-common words.

I assumed non clean input so I cleaned it before proceding.

The 'foo' 'barz' list is for easier testing. You may uncomment the line to read from a file.

```
LETTERS = ('a'..'z').to_a
SIMPLE_WORDS = ['foo', 'barz'] # File.read('words.txt').split("\n")

def non_common(text)
  text
    .downcase
    .chars
    .map { |char| LETTERS.include?(char) ? char : ' ' }
    .select { |char| LETTERS.include?(char) || char == ' '}
    .join
    .squeeze(' ')
    .split(' ')
    .select { |word| SIMPLE_WORDS.include?(word) }
end

p non_common('''djsh sjs
foo hsh^#^^@susns  dhd  djs d   #&#&@&  barz  e &2@&foo barz''')
```

Comment: In natural language processing, a technical term for simple words is [stop words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words).

Comment: Wait… I thought that the task was to return the non-common words, which I interpreted to mean all words _except_ the simple ones. Could you clarify your intention (and perhaps pick more plausible placeholders than `'foo'` and `'barz'`)?

Comment: @200_success, I am confused now, because initially I tried to run provided code which returned array of `'foo'` and `'barz'` String, so I assumed that's desired behavior. Now after your comment I don't know what is expected...

Answer (score 2):

To get an array of lowercase words, ignoring whitespaces, punctuation, special characters, etc.:

```
text.downcase.split(/\W+/)
```

To get an array of the common words from the words above and `SIMPLE_WORDS`, you can use the binary `&` operator:

```
text.downcase.split(/\W+/) & SIMPLE_WORDS
```

So we get:

```
SIMPLE_WORDS = %w(foo barz)

def non_common(text)
  text.downcase.split(/\W+/) & SIMPLE_WORDS
end

p non_common('' 'djsh sjs
foo hsh^#^^@susns  dhd  djs d   #&#&@&  barz  e &2@&foo barz' '')
#=> ["foo", "barz"]
```